# Is it possible to pass parameter to an assembly dll?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-assembly

Hello I have referred to [this article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/csharp/writinganactivexcontrolincsharp.aspx) The code works great and I am able to return values as shown in the article. This is a dll assembly which I am calling via javascript.

However, I would like to pass parameter into the interface and pull them into the class.

I have modified the code in the article tried the foll code:-

```
 public interface ASignatures 
 {
    void showMsg(string val);
 }
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)] 
 public class AClass :ASignatures 
 {
    public showMsg(string val)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(val);
    }
```

Above code does not execute and I cannot see errors as I am calling it via the javascript in browser. Please can you tell me if this is possible and if yes, then am I doing it wrong?

***Do I have to use something like GET or SET? Just guessing..***

**UPDATE 1**
If I put message box then they get displayed only if I donot have a parameterized function.. Example: I put messagebox.show in the code provided in article then it will show up.  Example: Following works and shows messagebox:-

```
    using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace ANamespace 
{

  public interface ASignatures
  {
    string FName();
    string SName();
    int Age { get;}  
  }

  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
  public class AClass :ASignatures
  {
    public string FName()
    {
MessageBox.Show("TEST THIS WORKS");
      return "Imran";
    }
    public string SName()
    {
      return "Nathani";
    }
    public int Age
    {
      get { return 24; }
    }
  }
}
```

But, now, I would like to pass a parameter to this DLL using :-

```
<script language="javascript">
    var x = new ActiveXObject("ANamespace.AClass");

    x.CallApp(PassSomeValueForExampleQueryString); //instead of x.CallApp()

  </script>
```

It worked, I had to do a CONTROL+F5!

Comment: You need to learn the difference between a web app and a desktop app, also what client side and server side mean

Comment: @MikeSW and Aristos, I am able to open message box if I edit the code from above article. There is no output only if I use parameterized function.. So I thought I will ask it in this forum.

Comment: Oh, it works well, had to do CONTROL+F5 ! :)

Comment: Are you aware that most Internet Explorer users will have their browsers set to reject ActiveX controls, and that most other browsers do not support them at all? You have chosen an obsolete, Microsoft-only technology, based on an article from seven years ago.

Comment: Yes, the solution is implemented on intranet with IE. Its OK for now.. But, could you point me to any new techniques to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is perfect as it is!.. It worked, I just had to do a CONTROL+F5 for browser refresh!